# Number of non negative integer ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $a^2-2^b=2023$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Number of non negative integer ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $a^2-2^b=2023$

What I try :

When $b=0,$ Then $a^2=2024$ No integer value exists

When $b=1,$ Then $a^2=2025\Longrightarrow a=45$

When $b=2,$ Then $a^2=2027$

When $b=3,$ Then $a^2=2031$

How can I find other non negative integer ordered pair.

Please have a look , Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If $b \ge 2$, then $a^2 = 2^b+2023 \equiv \ ? \pmod{4}$. Is this possible?